# How can I sketch the graph of these rational functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

For this, I know the vertical asymptotes are $x=-5, 5, 1, -1$ and the horizontal asymptote is $y=1$

I just graphed it and got this

[image]

I don't know how I would get the middle portion of the graph, do I just plot points and assume this is the shape?

Also I am supposed to sketch this graph so I don't know why I'd have to sketch so many points. I know how to find the x and y-intercepts.

Also:

[image]

I have this question and everything besides one $x$ cancels, am I supposed to graph it as $y = x$?

Comment: Note, the function $h(x)$ you describe agrees with the function $y=x$ for every $x$ *except* $-2019, -2017, -2015,\cdots, 2017, 2019$.  For those values of $x$ the function is officially undefined, though the function has a [removable discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity) at each of those locations.

Comment: As for the middle of the first graph, the only truly relevant bits of information for a crude sketch beyond the locations of the asymptotes and intercepts which you should already have are whether the function is increasing vs decreasing and positive vs negative.  For this, just look at how the function acts as it approaches each asymptote from the left and compare to how it acts as it approaches from the right, for example by looking at the sign of $h(1.0001)$ and comparing to $h(0.9999)$ (*not bothering to exactly calculate, just keep track of signs only*)

Comment: These old handouts of mine that I happened to find on the internet might be helpful: [Polynomial Graphs](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2697091-9755226-1202712/poly-graphs.pdf) ***AND*** [Six Graph Examples](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2697091-9755226-1202709/six-graphs.pdf) ***AND*** [Precalculus Supplementary Work](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2697091-9755226-1202714/HWS03-1.pdf).

Comment: but i'm still confused on how i'd know to graph a parabola alongside the two curves next to it

Answer (score 1):

When there are common linear factors in the numerator and denominator, the graph will be the graph of the simplified function after cancellations, but with missing points at the zeros of the denominator.

Here, for example, is the graph of

$$ f(x)=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-1)(x-2)} $$

[image: Missing Points]

In the example of the first graph which has no missing points to complicate the graph, there are several principles at work.

1. There is an $x$ intercept at each zero of the numerator
2. There is a vertical asymptote at each zero of the denominator
3. To the right of the right-most zero, whether it is of the numerator or denominator, the graph will remain entirely above or entirely below the $x$-axis depending upon the sign of the ratio of leading coefficients $p$ and $q$ of the numerator and denominator. In the example, that ratio is $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{1}{1}=1>0$ So the graph lies entirely above the $x$ axis on the interval $(6,0)$.
4. If the numerator and denominator have the same degree, then there will be a horizontal asymptote $y=\frac{p}{q}$
5. If the numerator is of higher degree than the denominator, then one may divide the denominator $D(x)$ into the numerator $N(x)$ to obtain a quotient $Q(x)$ and a remainder $R(x)$: $\dfrac{N(x)}{D(x)}=Q(x)+\dfrac{R(x)}{D(x)}$. In this case, the "tail ends" of the graph will approach the graph of $y=Q(x)$. $Q(x)$ is the quotient asmyptote.
6. If the numerator has lower degree than the denominator, then the $x$-axis is a horizontal asymptote of the graph, since $Q(x)=0$.
7. To begin the process of graphing, one graphs all intercepts and asymptotes, using dashed lines for the asymptotes. Next, one sketches the rightmost portion of the graph to the right of the largest zero, drawing it above or below the axis as per principle (3) and approaching the asymptote, whether a horizontal or quotient asymptote.
8. The word "transitive" means "crosses" and "intransitive" means "does not cross." This is an important concept with regards to $x$-intercepts and vertical asymptotes. The graph crosses the $x$-axis at transitive intercepts and vertical asymptotes, but remains on the same side at intransitive intercepts and vertical asymptotes. Transitivity of a zero depends upon its multiplicity. Suppose $(x-a)^n$ is a factor of either the numerator or of the denominator. Then the zero $a$ has multiplicity $n$. If $n$ is even, then $a$ is an intransitive $x$-intercept (or vertical asymptote) and if $n$ is odd, then $a$ is transitive. In your example, $n=1$ for all the zeros so the graph will cross at all intercepts and asymptotes. The graph "crosses" at an asymptote means the graph switches sides as it passes by the asymptote.
9. After one has correctly graphed the rightmost section of the graph, one procedes to the left either crossing or not crossing the $x$ axis at each intercept or asymptote until one reaches the leftmost part which must approach any horizontal or quotient asymptote.
10. For non-horizontal quotient asymptotes there is a principle seldom covered which is quotient intercepts. The graph will intersect the quotient asymptote at zeros of the remainder $R(x)$, either crossing or not-crossing the asymptote depending upon the transitivity of the zero.

Here is a better sketch of the graph:

[image: rational function graph]

Comment: so will it be just a straight line $y=x$ with holes at all points from -2019 to 2019?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: thank you! and for the first problem, do you know any way I can find out that weird shape in the middle with the two curves and the parabola inside it?

Comment: Yes, but that takes more explanation. I will amend my answer to explain the various principles involved. Check back in 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Notice that there is no intercept or asymptote between the two vertical asymptotes at $x=1$ and $x=-1$, so the graph does not cross the $x$-axis on the interval $(-1,1)$ but still must approach both of those two asymptotes. That accounts for the "weird shape" in the middle.